# Center x-axis labels in line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am building a line plot with two lines, one for high temperatures and the other for low temperatures. The x-axis is based on days over one complete year in datetime format (2014-01-01, etc.). However, I changed the labels–not the data–for months (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc). The problem is that the first label 'Jan' is in the origin. What I want is to **move all labels to the right to center them between ticks**.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.plot(x, y2)

# Change x-axis from %y-%m-%d format to %m:
monthsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%m')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthsFmt)

# Replace numeric x-axis labels (1,2,3, ..., 12) for abbreviations of months ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', etc.):
labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

# CODE GOES HERE TO CENTER X-AXIS LABELS...

# Render plot:
plt.show()
```

This is the **result that I am looking for**:

[image]

Comment: You are right, sorry. I already changed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering x-tick labels between tick marks in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158382/centering-x-tick-labels-between-tick-marks-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Thx but I already tried that solution (and many others in stack) but they do not work. Weird...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the minor ticks as suggested in the thread posted by DavidG should work. Below is a MWE that I've adapted for your specific problem, forcing the major ticks to appear on the first of each month and using the minor ticks to place the labels in-between the major ticks :

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime

# Generate some data for example :

yr = 2014
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x0 = datetime.datetime(yr, 1, 1)
x = np.array([x0 + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(365)])

y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(365)/365) + np.random.rand(365)/5
y2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(365)/365) + np.random.rand(365)/5 - 1

# Draw high and low temperatures lines :

ax.plot(x, y1, color='#c83c34')
ax.plot(x, y2, color='#28659c')
ax.fill_between(x, y2, y1, facecolor='#daecfd', alpha=0.5)

# Force the major ticks position on the first of each month and hide labels:

xticks = [datetime.datetime(yr, i+1, 1) for i in range(12)]
xticks.append(datetime.datetime(yr+1, 1, 1))
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', direction='out', top=False, right=False)
ax.axis([xticks[0], xticks[-1], -2.5, 1.5])
ax.set_xticklabels([])

# CODE GOES HERE TO CENTER X-AXIS LABELS...

labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
          'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
mticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks((mticks[:-1]+mticks[1:])/2, minor=True)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', length=0)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, minor=True)
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

which results in:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It often makes sense to use dates directly when plotting. So instead of manually setting fixed locations for the labels, one may use `matplotlib.dates` locators. To position ticks in the middle of the months, one could choose the 15th of the month,

```
matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=15)
```

A full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import random

df = pd.DataFrame(random.sample(range(10000),8760),
                  index = pd.date_range(start ='2013-01-01 00:00:00',
                                        end ='2013-12-31 23:30:00',
                                        freq='1H'),
                  columns =['value'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df['value'])
ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2013-12-31 23:30:00'))

months = mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth =(1,6,12), bymonthday=15 )
allmonths = mdates.MonthLocator()
m_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(allmonths)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.NullFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(m_fmt)
ax.tick_params(axis="x", which="minor", length=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works brilliantly for this simplified example. i have a more complex subplotting scenario where it doesn't work... will post another question.

Comment: My related question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037844/formatting-matplotlib-dates-locators-on-multiple-plots

Answer (score 0):

Almost, [Jean-Sébastien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4481445/jean-s%C3%A9bastien). It looks everything perfect but the last month. It does not show up.

Your solution tweaked a bit:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Draw high and low temperatures lines:
plt.plot(x, y1, color = '#c83c34')
plt.plot(x, y2, color = '#28659c')

# Fill area between lines:
plt.gca().fill_between(x,
                       y2, y1,
                       facecolor='#daecfd',
                       alpha=0.5)

# Force major ticks on a monthly time scale only:
locator = mpl.dates.MonthLocator()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)

# Hide major labels and set axis limits:
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.tick_params(axis='both', direction='out')
ax.axis(xmin=datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1),
        xmax=datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 31),
        ymin=-50, ymax=50)

labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
          'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

mticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks((mticks[:-1]+mticks[1:])/2, minor=True)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', length=0)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, minor=True)

plt.show()
```

The plot that I got is this one:
[image]

Any clue about what is needed to include December in the x-axis labels? Anyway, thx very much.

Comment: You need to set xmax as (2015, 1, 1)

Comment: I already tried. It gets worse, only plotting from Jan to June and five ticks

Comment: Everything looks ok on my setup. Does it change anything if you add a `plt.draw()` after setting the axis limits?

Comment: Maybe it is because of the renderer or matplotlib version. Otherwise I can't see what's wrong. I'll post an alternate solution with hard coded locations of the thickmarks, 1 sec.