# R: How to center the tick labels (putting labels between tick marks) using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was using R ggplot for data visualization, and I met the problem centering the tick labels between tick marks on x/y axes. Here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158382/centering-x-tick-labels-between-tick-marks-in-matplotlib) but the implementation is matplotlib.

This is what I had (the wrong version):
[image]

And this is what I expected:
[image]

THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: Something like `+ theme(axis.text.x=element_text(hjust=-0.5))`, see related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1330989/680068

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to reproduce your plot without the data you used to create the plot or the code you used to generate the plot

You can move the x-axis labels to the right by adding the following code to your plot

```
+ theme(axis.text.x=element_text(hjust=-0.5))
```

Additionally, one option might be just to rotate the x-axis labels instead of moving them. You can do this by adding the following code

```
+ theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90))
```